# OCR Simple example android using tesseract compilation error

Tags: android, ocr

I am making a library called `tesstwo`, and it works, but there's one problem when I'm trying to compile for Simple Android OCR. It says:

```
import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;
cannot resolve library
```

Does anyone know what the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: You will receive significantly more help if you take the time to check your grammar, spelling, and punctuation. If you write posts like the one here, nobody will take you seriously, and you will receive responses of the same poor quality.

Answer (score 2):

Hey i found the solution for it

all u need is to build ur Ndk and How to do that?
 Its simple

just take the path where to have saved the tess-two folder in the terminal(ubuntu)
for

```
Ubuntu:cd /home/workspace/tess-two-master/tess-two //This is my path u will have different
 tess-two$: /(path where u have installed ur ndk)/ndk-build

Windows:cd /cygdrive/e/terril/workspace/tess-two-master/tess-two ; /cygdrive/e/terril/Libraries/android-ndk-r8b-windows/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
```

It will work